# switch UIThreadDispatcher in platform (Unity) that does not have a built-in dispatcher

Tags: unity-game-engine, mvvmcross

I am using mvvmcross with Unity, but it doesn't have a built-in UIThreadDispatcher, there are many people had written it owns dispatcher which doesn't have a common interface. The following is my own implementation. Instead of create different MvxXXXUIThreadDispatcher, is there any other approach ?

```
public abstract class MvxUnityUIThreadDispatcher
: MvxMainThreadDispatcher
{
    protected MvxUnityUIThreadDispatcher()
    {
    }

    public bool RequestMainThreadAction(Action action)
    {
        UIThreadDispatcher.Instance.InvokeOrEnqueueOnMainThread(() => ExceptionMaskedAction(action));

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: This question might get more (and better) answers if it were tagged with `Unity` as well

Answer (score 0):

The thread dispatcher is used by Mvx to make sure that UI controls are not called on non-UI threads.

If Unity doesn't need this, then you can just call `action()` in your implementation.

In the https://github.com/et-nowis/mvx-unity-ngui MvvmCross implementation it looks like they used `SynchronizationContext`:

```
public abstract class MvxUnityUIThreadDispatcher
    : MvxMainThreadDispatcher
{
    private readonly SynchronizationContext _uiSynchronizationContext;

    protected MvxUnityUIThreadDispatcher()
    {
        if (SynchronizationContext.Current == null)
            SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new UnitySynchronizationContext());
        _uiSynchronizationContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
    }

    public bool RequestMainThreadAction(Action action)
    {
        if (_uiSynchronizationContext == SynchronizationContext.Current)
            action();
        else
            _uiSynchronizationContext.Post(state => ExceptionMaskedAction(action), null);
        return true;
    }
}
```

from https://github.com/et-nowis/mvx-unity-ngui/blob/master/Assets/External/MvvmCross/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Unity/Views/MvxUnityUIThreadDispatcher.cs - see source file there for their license terms on this code

Comment: Actually, I am one of the contributor for mvx-unity-ngui, SynchronizationContext is not work in Unity when deployed to ios device, so MvxUnityUIThreadDispatcher.cs is updated to use Action<Action> _dispatcher, but I don't know if this approach is good or not.